# Python datetime i need specific 30 second execute for loop

Tags: python-3.x

i need python loop condition execute every 1 minutes specific seconds loop run for an example now time 15:50:12 that time for loop run 15:40:30 next wait local time 30 second reach. Need run that correct time. 15:41:30,
15:42:30,
15:43:30

``````````
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd. read_excel('data.xlsx')
Time30 = now.replace(hour=00, minute=00, second=30)

for i in df.index:
    entry = df.loc[i]
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strptime('%S')

    current_time == Time30

    name_input = browser.find_element_by_name('fullname')
   password_input = browser.find_element_by_name('password")


`````````
``````````

Comment: Cant you use time.sleep(30)?

Comment: Sometime I getting error timeout exception. I need local time execution specific time seconds

Comment: so you want to run the loop only when the actual system time has 30 seconds mark and then onwards every iteration happens after 1 minute?

Comment: Yes,  for loop I'm using if condition so, i want specific system time seconds loop run. Wait specific system time it's reach that time execute next line otherwise wait system time it's is help my script.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gather, this should solve your problem

```
from time import sleep

# wait until seconds equal 30
while datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S").split(":")[2] != "30":
    pass

for i in range(10):
    print(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    # sleep for 1 minute in every iteration
    sleep(60)
```

You will need to modify this to suit your cause, but this is the general idea.

Thanks to @Pranav in the comments the first while loop can be optimised as follows

```
while datetime.now().second != 30:
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: 1. `datetime.datetime`objects have a `.seconds`. You don't get to format, split and compare the string. 2. A `while: pass` loop is going to make the program hang. You could do `sleep(1)` instead of `pass`

Comment: Thanks! I am still exploring much of python. As for your second point, what do you mean by hang? Something like a busywait which as opposed to sleep wont allow other threads to execute?

Comment: Yes, that is right. You can try it yourself. If you set the affinity of the p python thread to a single CPU, that CPU will be stuck at 100%

Answer (score 0):

If your function takes time, you can use this

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime


def main():
    # Do something
    ...


now = datetime.now().timetuple()
next_time = time.mktime(datetime(now[0], now[1], now[2], now[3], 30).timetuple())
while next_time < time.time():
    next_time += 30

while True:
    time.sleep(next_time - time.time())
    main()
    next_time += 30
```